# Algebra of Limits/Limits involving Greatest integer Function

Tags: limits

Is there any difference between the below two limits?
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\Big\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\Big\rfloor$$
$$\left\lfloor\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ represents the greatest integer function (floor function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it might seem to make sense that they would be the same, they're actually not:

$$\Big\lfloor\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\Big\rfloor = \lfloor1\rfloor = 1.$$

However, consider that $\sin x$ is well approximated by the Taylor polynomial $x - \frac{x^3}{6}$ for $x$ near $0.$ This means we can approximate $\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{6},$ which is less than $1$ for all real $x \neq 0$. So:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \Big\lfloor\frac{\sin x}{x}\Big\rfloor = \lim_{x \to 0} \Big\lfloor 1 - \frac{x^2}{6}\Big\rfloor = \lim_{x \to 0} 0 = 0.$$

This manipulation doesn't work because the floor function is not continuous.

Comment: Sorry, but I have edited my question, because my query was a bit different from what I actually asked earlier.‍♂️

Comment: No worries, I'll edit my answer accordingly